# When muting iframe API player, youtube.com player gets muted too

Tags: youtube-api

I have a function that mutes the youtube player in my page. I use the iframe API (player.mute() or player.unMute()). However, I noticed that this affects the player on youtube.com. When I go to youtube.com, the player will start muted. Any ideas?